# What software should I use to create a GUI application for authenticating and connecting a user to a server?

Tags: gui, server, vpn, vpn-server

I am new to programming.

So I created a VPS using ECS on the cloud. I'd like to create an application with the following features:

- Login authentication
- Various fields to enter server information
- Able to use simple obfuscation

I don't know where to start, if it's Python I must learn to create such a thing, then I shall learn Python, wherever this road leads me to!